# How to deal with Google "manual spam action" from inbound links?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress

I recently received from Google a notice that a WordPress site I administer is subject to a "manual spam action" due to "user-generated spam". The content they've flagged does not appear to be on my site, though--instead it's inbound links from other domains for bogus site searches, like "[my domain]/?s=[spammy Korean characters and link to probable porn site]".

I have submitted a link disavowal file via Google Search Console and asked that the action be reconsidered. But how can I prevent (for this and other WordPress sites) a similar problem from happening again?

Comment: It sounds like your site was hacked at some point.

Comment: Possibly, though as I said, there is no spam content on the site itself--it is all just links to searches of the site (that turn up no results).